# How to access a mysql database in google cloud platform in visual studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, google-cloud-platform

This is my first time creating an android app and I decided to use a mysql database to store my data. I then connected it with google cloud platform. How would I be able to send data to the database and retrieve data in visual studio? Ex creating a new user and sending their information to the database

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Tools > Extensions & Updates", click on "Online" and search for "Google Cloud Platform Extension for Visual Studio".

Once installed, you will find them in "Tools > Google Cloud Tools". 
 1. Add your Google Cloud account in "Manage Accounts".
 2. Go to the "Google Cloud Explorer > Google Cloud SQL", right click and "Add Data Connection" to your SQL instance.